# Menu migration update error

Tags: 8, migrations

I migrate the menu by this drush command:

```
drush migrate-import --update page_menu
```

and .yml config:

```
id: page_menu
label: 'Page menu migration.'
migration_group: pages
source:
  plugin: csv
  path: path_to_file/pages.csv
  delimiter: ';'
  # enclosure: '"'
  header_row_count: 1
  # These are the field names from the source file representing the key
  # uniquely identifying each node - they will be stored in the migration
  # map table as columns sourceid1, sourceid2, and sourceid3.
  keys:
    - id
  column_names:
    0:
      id: 'Unique Id'
    4:
      menu_name: 'Menu'
    5:
      menu_title: 'Menu title'
    6:
      menu_weight: 'Menu item weight'
ids:
  id:
    type: string
destination:
  plugin: entity:menu_link_content
  default_bundle: menu_link_content
  no_stub: true
process:
  bundle: menu_link_content
  title:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: row
      source: menu_title
      message: 'Field field_name is missing'
    -
      plugin: get
  menu_name:
    -
      plugin: skip_on_empty
      method: row
      source: menu_name
      message: 'Field field_name is missing'
    -
      plugin: get
  'link/uri':
    -
      plugin: migration_lookup
      migration: pages
      source: id
    -
      plugin: generate_path
  weight:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 0
  expanded:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 1
  enabled:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: 1
  changed: updated
migration_dependencies:
  required:
    - pages
dependencies:
  enforced:
    module:
      - custom_csv_import
      - migrate_source_csv
```

When I create menu items with this migration first time, the meigration works well. But if I want an update my menu with this command:

```
drush migrate-import --update page_menu
```

I get the error "Column 'bundle' cannot be null:":

```
      [error]  Drupal\Core\Database\IntegrityConstraintViolationException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'bundle' cannot be null: UPDATE {menu_link_content} SET bundle=:db_update_placeholder_0, uuid=:db_update_placeholder_1, langcode=:db_update_placeholder_2
WHERE id = :db_condition_placeholder_0; Array
(
    [:db_update_placeholder_0] =>
    [:db_update_placeholder_1] => 24013691-38b5-44bf-a981-9961620eb7a2
    [:db_update_placeholder_2] => en
    [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 21
)
 in Drupal\Core\Database\Connection->handleQueryException() (line 683 of C:\OSPanel\domains\example.loc\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Database\Connection.php).
 [error]  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'bundle' cannot be null: UPDATE {menu_link_content} SET bundle=:db_update_placeholder_0, uuid=:db_update_placeholder_1, langcode=:db_update_placeholder_2
WHERE id = :db_condition_placeholder_0; Array
(
    [:db_update_placeholder_0] =>
    [:db_update_placeholder_1] => 24013691-38b5-44bf-a981-9961620eb7a2
    [:db_update_placeholder_2] => en
    [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 21
)
 (C:\OSPanel\domains\example.loc\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage.php:783)
 [error]  Drupal\Core\Database\IntegrityConstraintViolationException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'bundle' cannot be null: UPDATE {menu_link_content} SET bundle=:db_update_placeholder_0, uuid=:db_update_placeholder_1, langcode=:db_update_placeholder_2
WHERE id = :db_condition_placeholder_0; Array
(
    [:db_update_placeholder_0] =>
    [:db_update_placeholder_1] => 36b7ae55-c15e-4be9-a857-ce811e6c9049
    [:db_update_placeholder_2] => en
    [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 22
)
 in Drupal\Core\Database\Connection->handleQueryException() (line 683 of C:\OSPanel\domains\example.loc\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Database\Connection.php).
 [error]  SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'bundle' cannot be null: UPDATE {menu_link_content} SET bundle=:db_update_placeholder_0, uuid=:db_update_placeholder_1, langcode=:db_update_placeholder_2
WHERE id = :db_condition_placeholder_0; Array
(
    [:db_update_placeholder_0] =>
    [:db_update_placeholder_1] => 36b7ae55-c15e-4be9-a857-ce811e6c9049
    [:db_update_placeholder_2] => en
    [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 22
)
 (C:\OSPanel\domains\example.loc\web\core\lib\Drupal\Core\Entity\Sql\SqlContentEntityStorage.php:783)
```

Where I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following basically means
 *use the default process plugin `get` to look for a source column or constant named `menu_link_content` to determine the value for `bundle`*.

```
process:
  bundle: menu_link_content
```

which most likely returns `null`.

Try setting it with the `default_value` plugin instead:

```
process:
  bundle:
    plugin: default_value
    default_value: menu_link_content
```

Comment: Yes indeed. That helped!